# Automation Anywhere Click on Cell by Text not working

Tags: automationanywhere

I am using Automation to automate a process that accesses a website and downloads some documents. I have to click on an item inside of a table. I can pull the index of the cell by text that I want to click on so I know that it is finding the correct cell, but when I tell it to click on the cell by matching the text, nothing happens. Anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvSgF.png)

Also, here is a screenshot of what the calendar on the webpage looks like.

[Webpage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWVY1.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions how to improve your question.

Comment: i hope you are using the object cloning. can you please attach some code snapshot of the object cloning Search Criteria.

Comment: Yes, I am using Object Cloning to pull the table then find an item in the table that matches the text of a variable then click on said item. I added a screenshot to my original question.

Comment: Check the domxpath, it should have captured the one date value during the object cloning. It will only work if you pass that particular value as input. Try get cell and set cell to get and set the values before clicking the particular cell.

Comment: @Noguarde Checking to see if this issue was solved.If not, could you edit your question to provide full captured domX path. Also you need to click the anchor tag and not the Table tag as in first screenshot